# Matplotlib patches change dash style

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I feel stupid for asking this.

I'm trying to plot a circle using patches and would like to change the line style to my own (offset, on-off-seq).

A small example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import patches

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

pa = patches.Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.4, fill=False, linestyle=(5, 10))
ax.add_patch(pa)

plt.show()
```

changing linestyle to e.g. `'--'` works fine, and according to the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Circle.html#matplotlib.patches.Circle), it takes this tuple as an input:

> linestyle or ls |     {'-', '--', '-.', ':', '', (offset, on-off-seq), ...}

yet, when running the above example I'm greeted with a type error: `'int' object is not iterable'`.

Did I misunderstand something here or is this a bug?

Comment: Yeah, it's essentially a bug, see [issue #11797](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11797). In this case though, the documentation is correct and you need a tuple `(offset, on-offseq)` instead of just `on-off-seq`; e.g. `linestyle=(0,(5, 10))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on-off-seq should also be a tuple, e.g

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import patches

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

pa = patches.Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.4, fill=False, linestyle=(5, (10, 2)))
ax.add_patch(pa)

plt.show()
```

You can use an even longer sequence of numbers, as long as the number of elements in that sequence is even, e.g. `(5, (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))`